# Spring Integration: The file is read twice from the folder

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have the following Spring Integration config:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
            auto-startup="true"
            channel="localInboundFilesChannel"
            directory="${in.received}"
            auto-create-directory="true">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="60" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:outbound-gateway
        auto-startup="true"
        request-channel="localInboundFilesChannel"
        reply-channel="localProcessingFilesChannel"
        directory="${in.processed}"
        auto-create-directory="true"
        delete-source-files="true"
        requires-reply="false"
/>
```

Poller runs every 1 minute copy files from one folder to another and the do something else (I do not provide code for next steps).

But when I put some file to directory I see that it is read twice, so in logs is see:

```
2017-08-11 14:06:31,250  INFO  org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=target\received\request.csv, headers={id=1f4d1ac0-823e-f3b0-2554-caae8e330682, timestamp=1502453191250}]]
2017-08-11 14:06:31,250  INFO  org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=target\received\request.csv, headers={id=73076423-f1ba-7cbe-a4c2-c5f02220e3f5, timestamp=1502453191250}]]
```

How I should fix it? Is there any issues in Spring Integrations beans configuration?

Comment: Does it happen once or each minute?

Comment: Perhaps you have somehow loaded 2 copies of the application context?

Comment: Any chance we can have a simple application to play from our side? What you show now is a standard behavior of that component. That's really would be bad to have such an unexpected state there out-of-the-box...

Comment: Yes, 2 copies of the application context were loaded, it was cause of issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you declare bean `FileReadingMessageSource` add a filter `org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Refer [IntegrationFlows with FileReadingMessageSource triggering job twice for same input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671336/integrationflows-with-filereadingmessagesource-triggering-job-twice-for-same-inp) for more information