# IntegrationFlows with FileReadingMessageSource triggering job twice for same input file

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a Spring Integration Batch job which is triggerred when the files are arrived:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileTriggeredIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(fileReadingMessageSource(),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(filePollerFrequency, filePollerInitialDelay)))
            .transform(toJobLaunchRequest())
            .handle(jobLaunchingGateway)
            .handle("jobCompletionHandler", "afterJob")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public FileReadingMessageSource fileReadingMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource sourceReader = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    log.info("Listening for {} files at {}", sourceFilePattern, sourceFileDirectory);
    sourceReader.setDirectory(new File(sourceFileDirectory));
    sourceReader.setFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(sourceFilePattern));
    return sourceReader;
}
```

It has been pretty smooth for long but recently I faced issue where the jobs ran twice for the same input file. Following is a snippet from log files:

> 2018-12-06 13:52:32,595 INFO  [**task-scheduler-7**] o.s.i.f.FileReadingMessageSource:380 - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/local/MY_INPUT_FILE.DAT, headers={id=ba1ad258-72cf-ed07-1175-3d1cc36f9bc1, timestamp=1544122352595}]]
>
> 2018-12-06 13:52:32,599 INFO  [**task-scheduler-10**] o.s.i.f.FileReadingMessageSource:380 - Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=/local/MY_INPUT_FILE.DAT, headers={id=ab8e9fbc-72a1-43e0-2ca3-8b8dcb3d91e5, timestamp=1544122352599}]]

If you see there are two threads marked in bold which have picked up the same files and triggered same job twice. Can someone please guide me how to avoid these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the same file is picked up from the `sourceFileDirectory` directory on the next polling cycle.

You need to consider to use an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` alongside with that `RegexPatternFileListFilter` as a composition in the `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also like to get this tested to avoid any issues in production. How can I get this tested?

Comment: You can take a look into the Spring Integration Testing Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context. I guess what you need is something like `MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler()` to verify that your `FileReadingMessageSource` produces only one file.

Comment: I created a valid file at a location and checked if that file is read using fileReadingMessageSource.receive() after which I deleted the file and created file with same name and checked that fileReadingMessageSource.receive() returns null.